# jQuery - Jtable Fields coming from database

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-jtable

I'm using jQuery jtable for my website, the jtable runs fine and there's no problem. But now I needed the fields to be dynamic. I mean, for example if the admin adds a subject on the table tblsubject on my db, it should be automatically added to fields on jtable init. Is that possible even possible?

I created a PHP code, actually the code is created with the help of other members here. that outputs the same format of fields in jtable :

```
General:{
title: 'General',
width: '30%',
list:false
}
```

-----> the php code:

```
$cons = mysql_query( 'SELECT Subject FROM tblsubject' );
$total_rows = mysql_num_rows($cons);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cons)) {
   $array[]= $row['Subject']. ': { <br/> title: \' '.$row['Subject'].' \',<br/> width: \'20% \' <br/>}';
}
$variable = implode(',<br/>', $array);
```

But when I include it on jtable

```
Fields{ <?php echo $variable; ?>}
```

the table didn't display.Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I really need it :D Thank you fellaz. All ideas and comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the old code..

```
$array[]= $row['Subject']. ': { <br/> title: \' '.$row['Subject'].' \',<br/> width: \'20% \' <br/>}';
```

Just remove the 
 and it will solve the problems. Also don't forget to change the `$_POST['fieldname']` on the query.

```
$array[]= $row['Subject']. ': {  title: \' '.$row['Subject'].' \', width: \'20% \' }';
```